# Easily remove the variable prefix in model.matrix()

Tags: r

Does anyone know a quick and easy way to prevent `model.matrix` from appending a prefix to the variable names?

Example:

```
A <- factor(sample(0:1, 5, TRUE), labels=c("X", "Y"))
B <- factor(sample(0:2, 5, TRUE), labels=c("Red", "Green", "Blue"))
model.matrix(~ A + B)
#  (Intercept)  AY  BGreen  BBlue
#1           1   0       0      1
#2           1   1       0      1
#3           1   0       0      0
#4           1   1       1      0
#5           1   0       1      0
```

However I would like to have something more like this:

```
#  (Intercept)  Y  Green  Blue
#1           1  0      0     1
#2           1  1      0     1
#3           1  0      0     0
#4           1  1      1     0
#5           1  0      1     0
```

Does anyone know of a really quick way to remove those prefixes?

Comment: Both `sample` won't work with `FALSE`

Comment: Also, your code is not always reproducible because sometimes `sample(0:2, 5, TRUE)` can give only two or less unique values and you won't be able to parse 3 labels to it. You should use `set.seed()` here

Comment: @DavidArenburg, clearly this is a toy example. But you're right, it is not a minimal working example.

Comment: It doesn't matter, every question should have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Could do

```
AB <- model.matrix(~ A + B)
colnames(AB) <- c(colnames(AB)[1], gsub("^[[:alpha:]]", "", colnames(AB)[-1]))

#   (Intercept) Y Green Blue
# 1           1 0     0    0
# 2           1 1     0    1
# 3           1 1     0    1
# 4           1 0     1    0
# 5           1 1     1    0
```

Not sure if the fastest way, but it will erase the first letters from your colnames using `gsub`

**Edit**

Alternatively, you could explicitly specify the variable names in `gsub` and remove them

```
AB <- model.matrix(~ A + B)
colnames(AB) <- c(colnames(AB)[1], gsub("^(A|B)", "", colnames(AB)[-1]))
```

Comment: This is a good approach David, but most often the variables I work with do not have the same length - so dropping the first letter is not quite flexible enough. :/